# Android application for connecting to wired Internet

Tags: android, internet, phone

I plugged cable into my PC and establish DSL pppoe connection. I want to be able to connect my smartphone to this wired Internet (no Wi-Fi or mobile network). I got adapters RJ-45 to USB and USB to micro-USB. Application should be trusted of course.
I want this in case if something happen with my computer, so that I could plug in cable into my phone, as mobile network may suck a lot of money from a phone.
That was once and while I was choosing a laptop though phone's mobile network it sucked out money couple of times.

Answer (score 1):

Try with simplert it has two programs one is client and one is app.

It is an open source project in development.

Reference:

https://github.com/vvviperrr/SimpleRT

https://androidcommunity.com/simplert-is-for-android-reverse-tethering-share-your-pcs-connection-to-android-20160801/amp/

Comment: Thanks a lot, really. That will be very useful for me. Though in my question I meant just cable into phone with no PC, in case if something happen with my PC. Once I had to buy new computer and I spend a lot of money on my phone using mobile network while was looking for a new laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is a bit late for the OP, but if someone comes around here, this is the best solution I found and no **root** is needed.

https://github.com/Genymobile/gnirehtet